# How can I quantify evidence of power law?

Tags: exponentiation

I have data from simulations I have run on FORTRAN, and the result looks like a power law relationship when plotting a log-log graph. How can I write this mathematically?

I've attached an image.

Thanks in advance.[Power Law Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvaVR.png)

Comment: Perhaps linear regression and look for a correlation coefficient close to $1$?

Comment: Relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108843/how-to-test-whether-a-distribution-follows-a-power-law